# Restful URL design full text search on any specified field

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

My api should support text search on specified fields. So I am thinking what kind of URL style handles it in the best way.

The below pattern, using **"q"** ,is mentioned in many blogs and documents to be used for full text search but I also need to specify field names:

**GET /groups?q=bank+org**

So I am thinking to use wildcards like below:

**GET /groups?name=*bank*&owner=*org***

I am just wondering if this is aligned with the best practices in the market?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Soheil, you are thinking right. "Search" is a "filter parameter" wich always go in the Query String.

Answer (score 0):

When sending parameters that will be used to query a collection of resources you *should* use... Guess what! *Query parameters*!

As far as I know, there's no *official documentation* that states that. It's a common approach and it's widely adopted. The only *offical documentation* about query string that I'm aware of is the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Quoting:

> [**3.4.  Query**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the [path component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI. [...]

For a full text search, you can choose the parameter you find most convenient. Do you think `q` is a good one? Go for it! But provide a good documentation for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I think I should rephrase my question :)

I know query parameters are very suitable to be used on searching a collection. I am thinking if using wildcards is the best way for full text search on **specified fields** or I need to change it like below for example:

**GET /groups?name_like=bank&owner_like=org**

instead of

**GET /groups?name=*bank*&owner=*org***

Thanks

Comment: @SoheilTorkAbadi The approach with the wildcards makes sense for me.